# xml within xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create something like this when I create xml:

```
<test <sometext=one /> />
```

how do I do something like this

Thank you

Comment: Well, this is not XML anymore. So you have to do that yourself. You will need your own writer and your own parser. Why not stick to XML? What is the benefit of this?

Comment: I am just asking can this be done..

Comment: As you've posted it, no, it cannot be done.  It's not possible to have xml as you've shown it anywhere, since it's not xml.

Comment: not as xml, it will just be a string.  It should be written as `<test><sometext="one" /></test>`

Comment: Some extension is possible like XAML does. <test><test.sometext> etc.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to create something like this when I create xml:

Sorry you can't create something like this in XML because this is not valid XML.

On the other hand you could embed XML in an attribute or a value of a node by properly encoding it. For example, as an attribute:

```
<test someattribute="&lt;sometext value=&quot;one&quot; /&gt;" />
```

Now the value of the `someattribute` attribute is the following XML: `<sometext value="one" />`.

Or if you wanted to embed the XML as the value of the node and not as attribute:

```
<test>&lt;sometext value="one" /&gt;</test>
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to create something like that, because that is not XML. There are a number of problems with your structure, and I suggest you reconsider the approach you are taking.

You will need to either create a child element or attribute containing the info you want. For example:

```
<test sometext="one"> </test>
```

or

```
<test>
<sometext>one</sometext>
</test>
```

Can you give some more info on why you would need such a structure?

Answer (score 0):

That's not XML so it's never going to work.

I great introduction to XML (including an XML Validator) can be found at [http://www.w3schools.com/xml/](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)